# WCF RESTful service and EF issue

Tags: .net, wcf, entity-framework, rest

I created database on Azure using EF Code first, and now i want to expose the data using WCF REST.

But, I am getting some strange behavior. When i want to return a list of(i.e. Item) my browser cannot simply retrieve it.

And when i rename the method so that returns string and return string.item, then it works :/

my **Web.config**:

```
<configuration>
 <connectionStrings>
  <add name="CijenolomciContext" connectionString="Server=tcp:*.database.windows.net;Database=myDataBase;User ID=*;Password=*;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="Cijenolomci2.Servis.Service" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
      <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Cijenolomci2.Servis.IService" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="web">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Item class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Item
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ItemID  { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false, ErrorMessage="You must enter a name!")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Name must be 50 characters or less")]
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Description must be 50 characters or less")]
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "You must enter a OldPrice!")]
    [DataMember]
    public Decimal OldPrice { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "You must enter a NewPrice!")]
    [DataMember]
    public Decimal NewPrice { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "You must enter a SaleStarts date!")]
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime SaleStarts { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime? SaleEnds { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

IService:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/items/", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<Item> GetItems();
```

Service.svc:

```
public List<Item> GetItems()
    {
        var result = db.Items.AsNoTracking().ToList();           

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The couple suggestions I can make are:

One of your `Item` classes properties is: `public virtual Category Category { get; set; }` Is the `Category` class also a `[DataContract]`?

Check Windows Event Viewer and see if there was an error logged. Sometimes if WCF errors are severe enough, and it is IIS hosted, then the w3wp.exe process will drop an error to the Windows log.

Turn on WCF trace logging (just Google "wcf trace logging") and see if it logs an error on the server.